# CakePHP 3 - How to create a model which doesn't have a table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm creating a REST API which has a method to generate a price for an order. The parameters for the order are passed via GET request, and the logic for calculating a price based on those parameters is quite large and complex.

I'm wondering how I can move that logic out of the controller to keep the code DRY and tidy.

I feel like the best solution would be to have a `Price` model of some kind, which is a class not linked to a table but expects to be created with the required parameters, and can then perform various tasks and ultimately give a price based on the variables. I would also like to be able to perform validation upon creation of the model, so that it can check it has all the required parameters and that they are valid.

- What is the best way to architect this?
- How do I create an "imaginary" model which is not really a table or proper entity?

Comment: u are after a modelless form i believe: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the best way to architect this?

By not using a table object because you don't want to interact with a table.

> How do I create an "imaginary" model which is not really a table or proper entity?

Data processing belongs clearly into the model layer. Model is a whole *layer* and not just about databases. This is a common mistake. So simply create your own set of classes or single class in the `src/Model/` or `src/Model/Calculator/` folder like `src/Model/Calculator.php` and then simply use namespaces and autoloading for use it where ever you want to use that.

```
use App\Model\Calculator;
$calculator = new Calculator();
```

You can use that class in the beforeSave() of a table object for example if you want to store the price somewhere.

I recommend you to always think in terms of responsibility and concerns and how to separate them. The calculator should do it's calculations, nothing more, it doesn't need to know *anything* about a database connection or table to do it's job. Read about [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: *"By not using a table object because you don't want to interact with a table."* - Exactly, I don't. Completely agree, and I always strive to strictly separate concerns within my apps. Was simply wondering if there is a specific "Cake way" of doing it which is already part of the framework. 

Your answer makes some sense, but does this actually allow me to leverage any of the built-in Cake functionality such as model validation? I'm also not sure if it's a good idea to be making calls for data from other tables in this custom model. It seems that would be violating MVC somewhat.

Comment: It's not a "custom model", it's a class within the model layer. A *calculator* is not supposed to do validation, it's scope is doing calculations. If you need to do something else create another class for that. Lookup the book.cakephp.org for validation and tableless forms. You can implement validation where ever you need it, read the book or look at the code how the form class that is used for tableless forms is doing validation.